# What is the Checksum of the elementary OS Loki Beta 2?

Tags: system-installation, release-loki

What is the Checksum of the elementary OS Loki Beta 2?

Comment: I believe this is a perfectly succinct question without being forced to include the superfluous text in order for it to be acceptable to the automated standards.

Answer (score 1):

```
elementaryos-0.4-beta2-amd64.20160716.iso
9454aff1631e68d5a69493ffba94542d0fcea7ed7d0b6d3e13c3bbac6ae46059
```

Comment: Did you just get it from your downloaded image, or did you find it from an official source?

Comment: I am the official source, I'm the one who uploads the images. Unfortunately, there is no current reference article for this.

Comment: Can you please post checksum of elementaryos-0.4-stable-amd64.20160909.iso?

Comment: Head over to https://elementary.io/en/docs/installation#verify-your-download, they are listed there.